# Why is useEffect not updating values as expected?

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks

I am tryin to get a mobile number validated with regex. Simple one: `+97798XXXXXXXX`.

I have these 3 states:

```js
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState("");
const [validMobile, setValidMobile] = useState(false);
const [focusMobile, setFocusMobile] = useState(false);
```

This is my `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setValidMobile(MOBILE_REGEX.test(mobile));
  console.log("validMobile: " + validMobile);
  console.log("mobile: " + mobile);
}, [mobile]);
```

When I check console on first mount, I have output as:

```
validMobile: false
mobile: (is there a way to avoid this as well **not the primary question**)
```

Then on each value entered to the field the output is as:

```
validMobile:false
mobile: numbers being entered
```

(I am matching regex, my entry is as +977981234567 which I can see in console as well.)

But now the problem arises:
When I press the last character, or the 10th character which should fulfill the regex test, the output is brain damaging:

```
validMobile: false (should be true as the regex is fulfilled.
mobile: +9779812345678
```

And the funny thing is if I add 1 more character then the output is:

```
validMobile: true
mobile: +97798123456789 (the last digit 9 breaks the regex)
```

It's as if the block of code is running with irregularities.

Here is my mobile input field:

```html
<input
  name="mobile"
  type="text"
  placeholder="mobile number"
  required
  autoComplete="off"
  onChange={(e) => setMobile(e.target.value)}
  onClick={() => setFocusMobile(true)}
  onBlur={() => setFocusMobile(false)}
/>
```

Please explain why is this happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: Protip: phrases like "odd behaviors" and "brain damaging" don't help us understand you. Please see [ask] and revise to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You likely do not need a `useEffect` for your use case, see React's docs on [when not to use `useEffect`](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state).

"validMobile" can be called as a regular function, its value can be computed and therefore does not need to be a state value.

```js
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState("");
const [focusMobile, setFocusMobile] = useState(false);

const validMobile = isValidMobile(mobile);
```